# Getting Security Groups in JWT Access Token

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory

I would like a JWT access_token to contain a list of security group.  From reading the documentation I attempted setting `"groupMembershipClaims": "All",` in the manifest of my application regostraton.

The setup is that I have a azure ad domain with 2 users. Then I have 2 groups: `[user, admin]`  Each user has one of the groups assigned to it.  Each group is of type `security`.

I am attempting to perform the OAuth Code flow manually, by going to the url formated similar to this:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantid>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<application-id>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&response_mode=query&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read&state=12345`

Then I login using the user account I setup in azure ad.  Then I use postman to submit a post request to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`  with parameters:

- `client_id` = `<client-id>`
- `code` = code from previous login,
- `redirect_uri` = `http://localhost:8080`
- `grant_type` = `authorization_code`
- `scope` = `user.read mail.read`

I get a valid response back, with an access_token.  However when I decode it there is no group claim listed at all.

How can I get the groups listed in the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the app to access own API, in order to get group claim in the access_token, you need to configure the `groupMembershipClaims` value as you want in the API manifest, then you could get the group claim information in the access_token.

But if the access resource is MS graph API or Azure AD graph API, you could not configure for them, you could only use the openid connect to get the id_token, and then you could see the group claim in the id_token. In your flow, you could add `openid` in the scope, then you could find the group information in the id_token.

I tried oauth2 code flow in the postman:

[image]

And it returns the access_token and id_token. To parse the id_token, I get the group information:

[image]

Comment: @Klouddy. I have updated my answer, please have a look. Maybe this will help you understand the `group` claim more clearly.

Comment: just to be clear, the groups are only present in the id token and not in the access token? I can't get seem to get the groups claim into the access token despite the documentation stating that this should work.

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, Azure AD v2 endpoint of Azure Active Directory does not yet support groups claims in its token. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims/). If you want to get all groups one user belongs to, you'll need query the groups from Microsoft Graph API. You can find the API documentation here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could define user roles in the app and assign those to the groups/users. Makes it a lot more transparent in AAD what access is given through the group.